# How to implements sharepoint's form based authentication on iPhone

Tags: ios, forms, sharepoint, authentication

We want to use webservice provide by sharepoint. Before we use the webservice , I neet to access the form authentication. Now I'm using a UIWebView to show the web site. It works, but I know it's not the correct way. Can anyone how to do this by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use authentication webservice provided by sharepoint, it works.